# C# currentItem.duration и currentmedia.duration библиотеки WMPlib возвращают 0

Tags: c#, .net, аудио

С#. 
Библиотека WMPLib. При попытке выяснить длинну файла в секундах currentItem.duration и currentmedia.duration возвращают 0. 
В URL есть адрес аудиофайла. 
Но все равно возвращается ноль.

```
    public double FileDuration { get { return wmp.controls.currentItem.duration; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать свойство `wmp.duration`.

```
public double FileDuration { get { return wmp.duration; } }
```

Comment: Пишите ответы более развернутыми. Добавьте минимальный пример, показывающий решение проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Дело в том что controls.currentItem.duration возвращает значение после непосредственного запуска файла. А не только по адресу файла в свойстве URL. 
То есть после метода WMPLib.controls.play().
Путаница произошла из-за того, что при реализации паттерна MVP запуск аудиофайла происходил позже вызова .duration.
Будьте внимательны.